# Fourier-like transformation with split-complex numbers?

Tags: fourier-transform, hypercomplex-numbers, split-complex-numbers

Usually the Fourier transformation is defined using the imaginary unit
$$
F(p) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{ipx} dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \cos px + i \sin px\ dx
$$
Now with [split complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number) one could come up with the idea to replace the imaginary unit $i^2=-1$ with $j^2=1$ and get in analogy a kind of hyperbolic Fourier transformation 
$$
F_h(p) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{jpx} dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \cosh px + j \sinh px\ dx
$$ 
Does such a transformation make sense? Would it have any use?

Comment: A potential issue is the growth rate of $\cosh$ and $\sinh$.  It seems like $F_h(p)$ will only converge for functions that are at least inverse exponential growth, although I haven't put too much thought into this.

Comment: If you split up your cosh and your sinh into exponentials you'll find that you're essentially performing Laplace transforms.

Comment: For potential reading, [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.1014.pdf) seems to look at "fourier transforms" in hypercomplex numbers (which the split complex numbers are a simple case of).  I haven't read it closely, but on page 8 they seem to go through and look at what properties must be followed for a hypercomplex Algebra (potentially multiple dimensions) to have a fourier transform on some plane spanned by two hypercomplex elements.  It seems like the conclusion they reach is for the plane to be isomorphic to $\mathbb C$.

Comment: As the split complex numbers contain no plane isomorphic to $\mathbb C$, their work would suggest the answer is "no".

Comment: Another reason this transformation may be of less interest than standard Fourier is that it's not as obvious how to invert it, because you'd need a result analogous to $\int_{\Bbb R}e^{ip(x-y)}=2\pi\delta(x-y)$.